# How to get files created in last 5 days and form a list for informatica source

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

Find all the files of the format yyyymmdd_test.txt created in last 5 days.
The file may not be available or created for a day in between as well.
i.e. for  5th june if following are the available files 
20150601_test.txt
20150603_test.txt
20150604_test.txt
20150605_test.txt

need to pick all these files for processing.
I need to create a list of the file names and give them as source for informatica workflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use this shell script which uses the **date** command's ability to do date arithmetic, in this case "-1 days" for example. The + part is the format.

```
for d in 4 3 2 1 0
do file=$(date --date="-$d days" +"%Y%m%d_test.txt")
   [ -f "$file" ] && echo "$file"
done
```